# Looking to convert String Column to Integer Column in PySpark. What happens to strings that can't be converted?

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm trying to convert a column in a dataframe to IntegerType. Here is an example of the dataframe:

```html
+----+-------+
|From|     To|
+----+-------+
|   1|1664968|
|   2|      3|
|   2| 747213|
|   2|1664968|
|   2|1691047|
|   2|4095634|
+----+-------+
```

I'm using the following code:

```html
exploded_df = exploded_df.withColumn('From', exploded_df['To'].cast(IntegerType()))
```

However, I wanted to know what happens to strings that are not digits, for example, what happens if I have a string with several spaces? The reason is that I want to filter the dataframe in order to get the values of the column 'From' that don't have numbers in column 'To'.

Is there a simpler way to filter by this condition without converting the columns to IntegerType?

Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest to try it yourself. With not so much effort you could create a small dataframe with some examples and see what happens when you convert.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the comment. I'm very new to this so I did not think of that at first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Values which cannot be cast are set to `null`, and the column will be considered a `nullable` column of that type. Here's a simple example:

```
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

sql_context = SQLContext(spark.sparkContext)

df = sql_context.createDataFrame([("1",),
                                  ("2",),
                                  ("3",),
                                  ("4",),
                                  ("hello world",)], schema=['id'])

print(df.show())

df = df.withColumn("id", F.col("id").astype(IntegerType()))

print(df.show())
```

Output:

```
+-----------+
|         id|
+-----------+
|          1|
|          2|
|          3|
|          4|
|hello world|
+-----------+

+----+
|  id|
+----+
|   1|
|   2|
|   3|
|   4|
|null|
+----+
```

And to verify the schema is correct:

```
print(df.printSchema())
```

Output:

```
None
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I just need to filter by null value, is None the correct way of filtering?

Comment: You can do `df.filter(F.col('x').isNull())` to get null values and `df.filter(F.col('x').isNotNull())` for non-null values.

Answer (score 1):

We can use **regex** to check does `To` column have some `alphabets,spaces` in the data, Using **`.rlike`** funtion in spark to filter out the matching rows.

**`Example:`**

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([("1","1664968"),("2","3"),("2","742a7"),("2"," "),("2","a")],["From","To"])

df.show()
#+----+-------+
#|From|     To|
#+----+-------+
#|   1|1664968|
#|   2|      3|
#|   2|  742a7|
#|   2|       |
#|   2|      a|
#+----+-------+

#get the rows which have space or word in them
df.filter(col("To").rlike('([a-z]|\\s+)')).show(truncate=False)
#+----+-----+
#|From|To   |
#+----+-----+
#|2   |742a7|
#|2   |     |
#|2   |a    |
#+----+-----+

#to get rows which doesn't have any space or word in them.
df.filter(~col("To").rlike('([a-z]|\\s+)')).show(truncate=False)
#+----+-------+
#|From|To     |
#+----+-------+
#|1   |1664968|
#|2   |3      |
#+----+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this alternative to converting the values to null.

Comment: @ecassinelli, As in the question mentioned I provided solution **`without casting`** to `Integer`!

Comment: Yes, sorry I wasn't clear, I'll try this instead of using to an integer, thanks!